# Variation of function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $f(t,v)$, $t\in[0,T]$, $v\in \mathbb R$ be absolutely continuous in $t$ for every fixed $v$ and absolutely continuous in $v$ for every fixed $t$. Let $X(t)$, $t\in [0,T]$ be a continuous function of unbounded variation on every interval $[t_1,t_2]\subset[0,T]$. I propose that if, for every $t$, $f'_v(t,v)\neq0$  a.e., then $f(t,X(t))$ is a function of unbounded variation.

Need help in proving this. I'll be thankful for any textbook recommendations on related topics.

Comment: Clearly false as stated. Take $f(t,v)=v^2$. Then you are claiming that $X^2$ is of unbounded variation if $X$ is of unbounded variation on every interval. Now take $X$ to be $+1$ at rationals and $-1$ at irrationals. 

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I forgot to mention that $X(t)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: That won't save you. Take any continuous function $X(t)$ with modulus of continuity $\omega(h)=o(\sqrt h)$. Let $f(t,v)$ be the distance from $(t,v)$ to the graph of $X$ in $\mathbb R^2$. $f$ is Lipschitz and for fixed $t$, $f_v(t,v)\ne 0$ for almost all $v\ne X(t)$ (just think where the closest point can possibly be and how the graph can go from there). However $f(t,X(t))$ is identically $0$.

Comment: If I got you right, then $f(t,v) = \min_s \sqrt{(X(s) - v)^2 + (t-s)^2}$ which has unbounded variation for every fixed $v$, while I consider functions with bounded variation.

Comment: And why are you so sure that it has "unbounded variation for every fixed $v$"? I'm sure that the variation is bounded because distance to anything is Lipschitz. What is your argument?

Comment: Well, you are right. Indeed it is of bounded variation and my statement is false. Can you give me any hints when such functions are BV and when not?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83545/variation-of-function#comment215095_83545) by [fedja](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1131/fedja). Consider
$$
f(t,v)=\min_s \sqrt{(X(s)-v)^2+(t-s)^2}.
$$
This function is Lipschitz, as the distance from $(t,v)$ to the graph of $X$. Whether or not $X$ has bounded variation, $f(t,X(t))$ is identically zero.